# Exception datagridview: there is no value for index 1

Tags: c#, datagridview

I can't seem to work out this one. 
See below code, when adding a (second) row to the datagridview (in running program) I get below exception thrown;

exception datagridview: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: there is no value for index 1. at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Item(Int32index) bij System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.GetError(Int32 rowindex)

have googled for solutions but cant seem to find the right one.
Anyone an idea how to solve this?

(have written other similar programs with more datatables in the dataset where i do not experience this problem so I really do not understand why it doesn't work, and I have just recently started to learn code :) )

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Garages
{
    public partial class FrmGarages : Form
    {
        DataSet datasetGarages = new DataSet("Garages");
        BindingSource bindingSourceGarages = new BindingSource();

        public FrmGarages()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            datasetGarages.Tables.Add(createDataTableGarages());
            bindingSourceGarages.DataSource = datasetGarages.Tables["Garages"];

            txbChassisnummer.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSourceGarages, "Chassisnummer");
            txbKenteken.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSourceGarages, "Kenteken");
            dtpFabricagedatum.DataBindings.Add("Value", bindingSourceGarages, "Fabricagedatum");
            dtpDatumOpKenteken.DataBindings.Add("Value", bindingSourceGarages, "DatumOpKenteken");
            txbMerk.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSourceGarages, "Merk");
            txbType.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSourceGarages, "Type");
            txbKleur.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSourceGarages, "Kleur");
            txbBrandstof.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSourceGarages, "Brandstof");
            txbAantalKilowats.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSourceGarages, "AantalKilowats");
            txbAantalPortieren.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSourceGarages, "AantalPortieren");
            txbModel.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSourceGarages, "Model");
            txbTrekhaak.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSourceGarages, "Trekhaak");

            cmbMerk.DataSource = bindingSourceGarages;
            cmbMerk.DisplayMember = "Merk";
            cmbType.DataSource = bindingSourceGarages;
            cmbType.DisplayMember = "Type";
            cmbBrandstof.DataSource = bindingSourceGarages;
            cmbBrandstof.DisplayMember = "Brandstof";
            cmbAantalPortieren.DataSource = bindingSourceGarages;
            cmbAantalPortieren.DisplayMember = "AantalPortieren";


            dgvGarages.DataSource = bindingSourceGarages;

        }

        private void btnEinde_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private DataTable createDataTableGarages()
        {
            DataTable dtGarages = new DataTable("Garages");

            DataColumn Chassisnummer = new DataColumn("Chassisnummer", typeof(string));
            Chassisnummer.Unique = true;
            dtGarages.Columns.Add(Chassisnummer);


            //dtGarages.Columns.Add("Chassisnummer", typeof(string));
            //dtGarages.Columns["Chassisnummer"].Unique = true;
            dtGarages.Columns.Add("Kenteken", typeof(string));
            dtGarages.Columns["Kenteken"].MaxLength = 8;
            dtGarages.Columns["Kenteken"].Unique = true;
            dtGarages.Columns["Kenteken"].AllowDBNull = true;

            dtGarages.Columns.Add("FabricageDatum", typeof(DateTime));
            dtGarages.Columns.Add("DatumOpKenteken", typeof(DateTime));
            dtGarages.Columns["DatumOpKenteken"].AllowDBNull = true;
            dtGarages.Columns.Add("Merk", typeof(string));
            dtGarages.Columns["Merk"].MaxLength = 25;
            dtGarages.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
            dtGarages.Columns["Type"].MaxLength = 25;
            dtGarages.Columns.Add("Kleur", typeof(Color));
            dtGarages.Columns.Add("Brandstof", typeof(string));
            dtGarages.Columns["Brandstof"].MaxLength = 10;
            dtGarages.Columns.Add("AantalKilowats", typeof(double));
            dtGarages.Columns.Add("AantalPortieren", typeof(byte));
            dtGarages.Columns.Add("Model", typeof(string));
            dtGarages.Columns["Model"].MaxLength = 15;
            dtGarages.Columns.Add("Trekhaak", typeof(bool));

            dtGarages.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { Chassisnummer };

            return dtGarages; 
        }

        private void dgvGarages_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.dgvGarages.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("Kleur"))
            {
                if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    this.dgvGarages.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value = colorDialog1.Color;
                }
            }
        }

        private void dgvGarages_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
        {
            dgvGarages.Refresh();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can't seem to find that as well. output window shows: Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Comment: I ran your code except I commented everything in the constructor except the first 3 lines and the last line and do not get the error.  The only error I get is when column 2 of the DGV is not unique.  So I add data to column 1 & 2 in first row, then and data in row 2 columns 1 & 2 and no error.

Comment: can you put debugger in `createDataTableGarages()` method and check if any error throwing while adding columns to `DataTable` (copy exception message here)? I guess Problem is when you are trying to add the columns to dt.

Comment: jdweng, you are right, did so myself and no error. can't really understand why though, can you give an explanation what i did wrong in the code you commented?